# Using "respectively" with "and" vs. "or"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, conjunctions, collocation

Is it acceptable usage to use "or" with "respectively", or is it possible only with "and"?

Example:

> If the light changes from red to blue or from blue to red, you must catch or throw the ball, respectively.

I've seen lots of construction with "and" but none with "or".

Answer (score 2):

Using *and* would turn this sentence into a [garden-path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) one:

> If the light changes from red to blue or from blue to red, you must catch and throw the ball, respectively.

The reader will parse *catch and throw* as a single unit ("whenever the light changes in whichever direction, catch the ball and throw it"), then stumble and fall over the *respectively* that makes no sense, be forced to go back and re-parse.

So the sentence is fine as written.

Comment: -1 However, the question is whether one can use *respectively* with 'or'. Or not.

Comment: @Kris: "The sentence is fine as written".

Comment: However, it still begs the question why.

Comment: So is it ok to use `or` on the both sides? example: `Program calls a script (A or B) when the state of a job is changed to B or C, respectively.`